# CI 3 to CI 4 Encryption Compability

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have 1 app for SSO, use CI 3. Now i am creating new app with CI 4.
code in CI 3 for encryption :

```
$otp = 123;
$this->encryption->initialize(array(    
    'cipher' => 'aes-256',
    'mode' => 'ctr',
    'key' => '12345678901234567890123456789012'
));
echo $this->encryption->encrypt($otp);
//result 54322c75199be967a78c4d65906dd1d6a41c54027ddb2ff1a295c5646728f435cf4c3b5e793b57b6a6ecef34de7b7c1ed809632adeb02c5fabdf5f76befe4440PFRX6XAktE/jZXJKjL8fhCcqQw==
```

code in CI 4 for decryption :

```
$otp = '54322c75199be967a78c4d65906dd1d6a41c54027ddb2ff1a295c5646728f435cf4c3b5e793b57b6a6ecef34de7b7c1ed809632adeb02c5fabdf5f76befe4440PFRX6XAktE/jZXJKjL8fhCcqQw==';

$config         = new \Config\Encryption();
$config->key    = '12345678901234567890123456789012';
$config->driver = 'OpenSSL';
$encrypter = \Config\Services::encrypter($config);
echo $encrypter->decrypt($otp);

//result CodeIgniter\Encryption\Exceptions\EncryptionException Decrypting: authentication failed.
```

i have try with different option :

```
$config         = new \Config\Encryption();
$config->key    = '12345678901234567890123456789012';
$config->driver = 'OpenSSL';
$config->digest = 'sha256' or 'sha512';
```

Still getting message authentication failed. but in this [documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/encryption.html#id5) states that my CI 3 configuration it same with CI 4 even with default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one seem interesting to the subject. i have figure it out hot to resolve this problem.
so. what i am doing is. take / copy Codeigniter 3 encryption class from `system/libraries/Encryption.php` and make it third party Library in Codeigniter 4 and put it in `app/libraries/Ci3encrypt.php` (i rename it to this because i'm afraid the class name be the same with ci4 class)

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class Ci3encrypt
{
//and the rest is still the same
```

to call new class. in CI4 on the controller i put

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Libraries\Ci3encrypt;
```

and on the function in controller ci4

```
$ci3 = new Ci3encrypt();
$ci3->initialize(array( 
    'cipher' => 'aes-256',
    'mode' => 'ctr',
    'driver' => 'openssl',
    'key' => '12345678901234567890123456789012'
));
$plain_text=$ci3->decrypt($ciphertext);
```

and my problem is resolve. finally

for more information visit :

https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/pull/6277
https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=82494

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have wrong "digest" value.

CI4 ~config/Encryption.php

I set `public string $digest = 'SHA512';`

Now my file

```
<?php
```

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Encryption extends BaseConfig
{

```
public string $key = 'key';

public string $driver = 'OpenSSL';

public int $blockSize = 16;

public string $digest = 'SHA512';

public bool $rawData = false;
public string $encryptKeyInfo = 'encryption';
public string $authKeyInfo = 'authentication';

public string $cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
```

}